# How to use modal to create a new object in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

This is the current situation, a general rails  app with `index.html.erb` related to `index` action, and a `new.html.erb` with `new` action to create a new object.

My request is that I want to use modal to replace the index.html.erb to create a new object. In detail, when user click a `New` Button in the `index.html` page, a dialog display with a form of creating object, instead of opening the new.html page.

Is there a possible way to realise this ignoring copying the code in `new.html.erb` to `index.html.erb`? Because it would also move the code in new action to index action.

I have tried an approach below, but it didn't meet my requirement:

`<%= link_to "New sites", new_site_path, :class => "btn btn-primary", "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => ".bs-example-modal-lg" %>`

It would open a modal dialog including the components in `application.html.erb`, such as navigation bar ,side bar and so on, not only the creating form.

Comment: I guess you're opening a `modal` on the index page after clicking on the `New Sites` link, right? can you post your `modal` form please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set "layout false" in action